# How long can I power up a nodeMCU

Tags: power-supply, esp8266, nodemcu, iot

I have a **nodeMCU esp8266** and I'm going to power up the nodeMCU as long as possible but I need to know is it good to the health of nodeMCU. In other way I am going to power the nodeMCU forever.(Something Like this)

Comment: Not quite certain about what you are asking. Do you want to know how much it will work before breaking down? ask the ESP2866 manufacturers. A conservative guess would be at least 5 years. Also see this https://www.reddit.com/r/esp8266/comments/a4lwbq/long_term_stability_and_reliability_of/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had several powered up and running for > 6 months without restart or interruption.  Many commercial devices (WiFi IOT like smart switches, bulbs and dimmers) use the esp8266 with a similar design that run for years at a time without issue.

There is nothing in the design that should prevent you running one for years at a time.

Dean

Comment: Did you connected fans for the esp8266 modules.

Comment: No, no fan or heat sink needed regardless of the amount of WiFi data you send.  As long as you are providing a decent 5V power supply you will be fine.